# On the proof there is no Lebesgue measure on infinite-dimensional, separable Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

I am trying to understand the proof provided on
[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite-dimensional_Lebesgue_measure#Proof_of_the_theorem)
that there is no Lebesgue measure
on infinite-dimensional, separable Banach spaces.
This proof starts by saying that
if $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is such a Banach space,
and $\delta > 0$,
and $B$ is an open ball of radius $\delta$,
then there is a sequence $(B_n)^\infty_{n=1}$
in $B$
of pairwise disjoint open balls of radius $\delta/4$.
Why is that?

For convenience, suppose that $B$ is centered around $0$.
I understand that if $X$ is the Hilbert space $\ell^2$
of square summable sequences,
then it has a basis $(e_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ defined by
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
e_1&=(1,0,0,0,\ldots)\\
e_2&=(0,1,0,0,\ldots)\\
e_3&=(0,0,1,0,\ldots)\\
\text{etc.}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
and one can obtain a sequence $(B_n)^\infty_{n=1}$
of pairwise disjoint open balls in $B$,
each of the same strictly positive radius,
by centering each $B_n$ around a certain multiple of $e_n$.

But how to show this for general infinite-dimensional, separable Banach spaces?

Comment: Perhaps construct a basis with your Hilbert space example as a guide.  You have a countable basis by assumption, and it looks to me like angle doesn't matter here as much as distance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no translation invariant measure $\mu$, such that $0<\mu\big(B_r(x)\big)<\infty$, for every ball, with $r>0$.

In the case of $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, observe that
$$
B_{½}(e_i)\cap B_{½}(e_j)=\varnothing, \quad i,j\in\mathbb N,\,\,i\ne j, 
$$
and
$$
\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N}B_{½}(e_i)\subset B_2(0),
$$
and hence, if such a measure existed, then we would have that
$$
\mu\big(B_{½}(e_i)\big)=\mu\big(B_{½}(e_j)\big), \quad
\text{for all $i,j\in\mathbb N$,}
$$
and
$$
\infty=\sum_{i\in\mathbb N}\mu\big(B_{½}(e_i)\big)\le \mu\big(B_{2}(0)\big)
$$